# ubuntu pro: Downgrade from paid to free

Tags: downgrade, ubuntu-pro

I've retired and would like to downgrade my ubuntu pro from paid to free. I have one server on a subscription. What is the right way to do this? I don't see an obvious path in the ubuntu pro menu options to do this.
Thanks!

Comment: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-cancel-an-ubuntu-pro-trial-subscription/31521

Comment: You have to ask Canonical. Over here we are just users helping each other solve problems we face with Ubuntu.